# MULTIPART_FORM_DATA support for REST clients

Tags: rest, jax-rs, multipartform-data

I'm quite to new `REST` webservice and using `Jersey` implementation of `JAX-RS`.

My question is, if I create a webservice that accepts a file upload that  `@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)`, then `@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)` `MIME` type is capable of handling "file upload" request from any sort of client ?

I can imagine the client can accomplish the call using `Java`, `.NET` and so on. But does `MIME` `MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA` type is supported in all possible calling clients. And of course, is it safe to assume that below file upload works for any sort of client ?

```
 @POST
 @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
 @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
 public String uploadFile(@PathParam("fileName") final String fileName,
   @FormDataParam("userId") final int userId) {
  //.......
 }
```

Comment: Any client with a correct implementation of http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2388 are supported.

Comment: thanks for the link.